# comparing between rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I compare all the rows value(sum) in my table to the first row (which is the first date)

for example:

```
ID   Date       Sum
 1  01-01-2020  60
 2  01-02-2020  70
 3  01-05-2020  80
 4  01-06-2020  25
```

I want all the IDs which the sum in them is greater than 60 (the first date)
I tried to set the first date as min(date) but I can't compare the sums inside the date.

The result should be:

```
ID   Date       Sum
 2  01-02-2020  70
 3  01-05-2020  80
```

Comment: are you talking about two tables??

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from mytable where sum > (select sum from mytable order by date limit 1).
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*, first_value(sum) over (order by date) as first_sum
from t;
```

You can then incorporate this into a subquery to get the rows that are at or exceed the value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, first_value(sum) over (order by date) as first_sum
      from t
     ) t
where sum > first_sum;
```

You can also do this with a `cross join`:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select t.*
      from t
      order by date asc
      limit 1
     ) t1
 where t.sum > t1.sum;
```

Or do the same thing with a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sum > (select t2.sum
               from t t2
               order by t2.date
               limit 1
              );
```